# Can't install Torch despite Cuda 8.0 and nvidia-driver 375 with GTX 1060

Tags: lua, installation, nvidia, torch

I am currently trying to install torch on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I have installed Cuda 8.0 and nvidia-smi gives me the version 375.66 that I'm using.

However, I get the following error-message when trying to run

```
./install.sh
```

From within the `~/torch` folder.

```
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/lbfgs.lua
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/checkgrad.lua
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/adamax.lua
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/ConfusionMatrix.lua
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/adadelta.lua
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/rmsprop.lua
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/logger.md
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/intro.md
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/image
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/image/parameterflattening.svg.png
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/image/parameterflattening.svg
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/image/parameterflattening.png
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/algos.md
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/doc/logger_plot.png
-- Installing: /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/optim/1.0.5-0/lua/optim/README.md
Updating manifest for /home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks
optim 1.0.5-0 is now built and installed in /home/yenicelik/torch/install/ (license: BSD)

Found CUDA on your machine. Installing CUDA packages
Warning: unmatched variable LUALIB

jopts=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_CONF)

echo "Building on $jopts cores"
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. -DLUALIB= -DLUA_INCDIR=/home/yenicelik/torch/install/include -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/yenicelik/torch/install/bin/.." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/yenicelik/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/cutorch/scm-1" && make -j$jopts install

Building on 4 cores
-- Found Torch7 in /home/yenicelik/torch/install
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found suitable version
  "7.5", minimum required is "6.5")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/yenicelik/torch/install/share/cmake/torch/FindCUDA.cmake:1009 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yenicelik/torch/extra/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/yenicelik/torch/extra/cutorch/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I assume it's a pretty simple mistake, but I'm not sure why it's failing.

Comment: did you add cuda to your PATH?

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be helpful for someone else. My nerves were mixed up because  of that.
So,

- a libcudart7.5 is maybe installed in the system. Look for this kind of reference.
- Build a link, if it'sn't done from /usr/local/cuda-8-0 to /usr/local/cuda (sudo ln -s *from* *to*).
- use the ./clean.sh file or, more violent, destroy the torch directory and clone a new one. The references are not rebuilt after an error.
- install and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error totally same. Just:

```html
sudo rm /usr/bin/nvcc
```

and use your cuda installed mannuly in /usr/local/cuda-***